# Get clicked point in Devexpress line chart without visible markers

Tags: winforms, devexpress, linechart

I'm trying to get clicked point on a deveexpress 1.14 line chart in winforms. It works fine with LineSeriesView MarkerVisibility set to true, but I don't want the points to be marked like that, i want a smoth line. How can i get the Seriespoint without doing that?

```
private void chart_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  // Obtain the object being clicked.
    ChartHitInfo hi = chart.CalcHitInfo(e.X, e.Y);
    // Check whether it was a series point, and if yes - 
    // obtain its argument, and pass it to the detail series.
    SeriesPoint point = hi.SeriesPoint; // hi.SeriesPoint IS NULL

    if (point != null) {
       // do stuff

    }
}
```

The runtimeHitTesting is on for that chart
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacked:

```
void chart_CustomDrawSeries(object sender, CustomDrawSeriesEventArgs e)
    {
        LineDrawOptions drawOptions = e.SeriesDrawOptions as LineDrawOptions;
        if (drawOptions == null)
            return;
        drawOptions.Marker.Color = Color.Transparent;
        drawOptions.Marker.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
```

Remeber to set  `this.chart.CacheToMemory = true;  so the event don't fire all the time.